Reverse triangle inequality for $\|\cdot\|^q$
Suppose we are given a normed space $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ and $q\geq1$. It is well known that for every $x,y\in E$
$$\|x-y\|^q\leq 2^{q-1}(\|x\|^q+\|y\|^q).$$
I am wondering if there exists a reverse kind of inequality of the form
$$|\|x\|^q-\|y\|^q|\leq C_q \|x-y\|^q?$$

There doesn't exist such an inequality: consider $(\mathbb{R}, \mid \cdot \mid)$ and the points $x_n = n+1, y_n=n$. Then the inequality would imply that
$$
(n+1)^q - n^q \leq C_q
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. But for $q \geq 2$ such a constant $C_q$ can clearly not exist, since then
$(n+1)^q - n^q \geq n.$

Thank you for your response. Do you have an idea on how I could adjust the desired inequality to make it valid and rule e.g. your counterexample out?

@El_mago for $q=1$ the inequality is true and useful as you perhaps know (with $C_q =1$). For $q>1$ one obvious thing to try would be to multiply the right hand side not by $C_q$, but by some continuous function of the norms of $x$ and $y$. But if you think a bit about my example, you'll see that such a function must be huge, and so if such a function even exists, it wouldn't be very useful. I think Fnacool's example already implies that such a function in fact cannot exist.

More generally, let $q>1$, $\|x\|=1$ and set
Let $y = cx$ for $c>1$.  Then $\|y-x\|^q =(c-1)^q$, while $\|y\|^q - \|x\|^q =c^q-1$. Now
$$\frac{c^q - 1}{(c-1)^q}= \frac{c^q-1}{c-1} \times \frac{1}{(c-1)^{q-1}}.$$
Now let $c\to 1$. The right-hand side tends to infinity.
